# Standards: attribute order in HTML

Tags: html, standards

I've been working on updating the coding standards for my web development organization. One aspect of this that has proven contentious among my co-workers is the ordering of HTML attributes. One co-worker, and many sources I have found online, suggest that class or id should come first, followed by others in order of importance.

```
<a class="foo" href="/bar/baz.html">Link</a>
```

Supposedly, this aids in readability. I'm not so sure in this case. Sometimes, when people say something is more readable, what they mean is that they have become accustomed to a certain pattern, and can't browse as easily without the pattern. Which is really more subjective than readability. Another co-worker suggests (and I happen to agree with him) that the defining attribute of the element should come first, and then any presentational or organizational attributes should follow. The essence of the anchor tag is the href attribute.

```
<a href="/foor/bar.html" class="baz">Link</a>
```

This might be trivial on an anchor tag, so what about an input tag? 
When scrolling through a form, I want to know right away what the input's type is: text, radio, button, etc. Class can come later.

How do the rest of you feel about this topic? I'm interested in hearing any arguments for both sides. Maybe we shouldn't even be worrying about this particular bit of syntax?

Comment: This Question doesn't belong to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is a Q&A Site and not the best place for discussions. This Question is primarly Opinienbased and therefore leads to discussions

Comment: Can you recommend an appropriate place to ask this question?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it doesn't matter at all. In terms of personal preferences, all that matters are the personal preferences of those on your team.

My personal preference is that this is minutia and overhead that no one really should be dwelling on.